# Rendering golang template defining the same block multiple times

Tags: go, templates, layout

I have a layout template (`base.tmpl`) that I would like to use several times in login page (`login.tmpl`), main content page (`main.tmpl`), and so on.

`base.tmpl` file:

```
{{define "base"}}
<html>
    <head>
        {{block "header" .}}
            <title>Untitled</title>
        {{end}}
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="main-content">
            {{block "content" .}} {{end}}
        </div>
        {{block "footer" .}} {{ end}}
    </body>
</html>
{{end}}
```

The pages have a first directive to use the `base` layout and they can define `header`, `content` and `footer` blocks.

`login.tmpl` file:

```
{{template "base"}}

{{define "header"}}
    <title>Login</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
{{end}}

{{define "content" }}
    <input type="username">
    <input type="submit" value="Login">
{{end}}
```

`main.tmpl` file:

```
{{template "base"}}

{{define "header"}}
    <title>Main content</title>
{{end}}

{{define "content" }}
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
{{end}}

{{define "footer" }}
    <script>console.log("ok");</script>
{{end}}
```

Loading and render template functions:

```
// 'templates' is a global variable
func LoadTemplates(files []string) {
    templates = template.Must(template.New("myTemplates").ParseFiles(files...))
}

func Render(w http.ResponseWriter, tmpl string, data interface{}) {
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, tmpl, data)
}
```

Using my code to render login page:

```
// the following line is a simplification, actually I load all files together once.
LoadTemplates(string[]{"base.tmpl", "login.tmpl", "main.tmpl"})
Render(w, "login.tmpl", struct{}{})
```

Using my code to render main content page:

```
// the following line is a simplification, actually I load all files together once.
LoadTemplates(string[]{"base.tmpl", "login.tmpl", "main.tmpl"})
Render(w, "login.tmpl", struct{}{})
```

**The problem is that the content block is overwritten because it is twice. So, if I render login or main page, I see the same.**

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to have multiple template "sets" as answered here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11468132/2908337