# How to do nesting in golang correctly?

Tags: html, go, templates

In this code, I made a `base.html` file to stop the repetition of the `HTML` code in each file. I used the `{{define ".."}}` and `{{template ".." .}}` properly in both `home.html` and `about.html`.

But when I run the code, and visit `localhost:8080` or `localhost:8080/about`, it only gives the result of the `home.html` file. Although for the `/about` link, it should give the result of the `about.html` file.

**main.go**

```
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler.Home)
    http.HandleFunc("/about", handler.About)
    fmt.Println("Starting the server at :8080")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**handler.go**

```
func init() {
    tmpl = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/*.html"))
}

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "home.html", nil)
}

func About(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, "about.html", nil)
}
```

**base.html**

```
{{define "base"}}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>{{template "title" .}}</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section>
        {{template "body" .}}
    </section>
</body>
</html>

{{end}}
```

**home.html**

```
{{template "base" .}}

{{define "title"}} Home page {{end}}

{{define "body"}} 
    <h1>Home page</h1>
    <p>This is the home page</p>
{{end}}
```

**about.html**

```
{{template "base" .}}

{{define "title"}} About page {{end}}

{{define "body"}} 
    <h1>About page</h1>
    <p>This is an about page</p>
{{end}}
```

Comment: You need to show how you register your HTTP handlers.

Comment: This question have already been answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467731/is-it-possible-to-have-nested-templates-in-go-using-the-standard-library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use must create your templates separately, for each page include base.html and page.html:

```
var tmpl = make(map[string]*template.Template)

func init() {
    tmpl["home"] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/home.html", "templates/base.html"))
    tmpl["about"] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles("templates/about.html", "templates/base.html"))
}

func Home(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl["home"].ExecuteTemplate(w, "home.html", nil)
}

func About(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tmpl["about"].ExecuteTemplate(w, "about.html", nil)
}
```

Comment: I implemented the code, but it is loading no page.

Comment: @sikandarmeranam could you share your updated code (create github gist or similar)?

Comment: I wrote all the functions in `main.go` and removed the functions in `handler.go` and it worked but when I write the functions in `handler.go`, and call them in the main function, it does not work. Although I call the functions like this `handler.Home`