# Dynamically parse sub-templates based on those actually required by the main template

Tags: go, go-templates

Suppose I have a large number of templates with sub-templates, then how do I parse [sub-templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467731/is-it-possible-to-have-nested-templates-in-go-using-the-standard-library) based on those required by `template` pipelines in the?

My idea is to read the current template to be rendered and find out which templates it uses, but I don't know how to do that, perhaps with regular expressions?

PS: answers don't have to consider multi-level nesting of sub-template.

---

Example

```golang
package main
import (
    "html/template"
    "path/filepath"
)

func CollectFiles(dir string, excludeList []string) (fileList []string, err error) {
    // ...
    return
}

func main() {
    filePathList, _ := CollectFiles("dir/src", []string{".md"})
    for _, curFile := range filePathList {
        _, _ = template.New(filepath.Base(curFile)).
            ParseFiles(curFile, "tmplA", "tmplB", "...", "tmplN")
    }
}
```

Suppose the main template only needs  `tmplA` and `tmplB` as sub-templates. How can I detect that it only requires those two?

I don't want to change the program every time a new template is added or adjusted.

Comment: why cant you parse all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the keywords in the template in this way.

```golang
regexp.MustCompile(`{{-? ?(template|partial) \"([^() ]*)\" ?.* ?-?}}`)
```

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WHJORa/1)

where `partial` is just an example for you to use when you have more complicated situations. You can delete it or add more keywords by yourself.

<kbd>[go-playground](https://go.dev/play/p/inBiNuMQMHk)</kbd>

---

The other parts, such as the `CollectFiles` I think are not so important, if someone needs to refer to the following

- [solution of embed](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-example-parseFile/blob/e33bca58b16896f401215cb6be325e2a6cfee3b1/src/main.go#L70-L87)
- [solution of filesystem](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-example-parseFile/blob/e33bca58b16896f401215cb6be325e2a6cfee3b1/src/main.go#L89-L98)

---

And then just need to [filter](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-example-parseFile/blob/e33bca58b16896f401215cb6be325e2a6cfee3b1/src/main.go#L142-L165) templates to find out what templates the current file uses.

---

Finally, the [code](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-example-parseFile/blob/e33bca58b16896f401215cb6be325e2a6cfee3b1/src/main.go#L172-L174) without to update whenever a template is added. (except you want to update the site context)

---

I wrote a simple [example](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-example-parseFile/blob/e33bca58b16896f401215cb6be325e2a6cfee3b1/src/main.go) on Github that can run so that people can know what I want to do.

#### Nesting of sub-template.

If you want to handle this. try to use this [function](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-example-parseFile/blob/cb906b035532862347d4df61cb89d63868b5276b/src/main.go#L106-L142)

Now this will work

If you render: `index.gohtml` not only `base.gohtml` include but also {`head.gohtml`, `navbar.gohtml`, `footer.gohtml`} are included

```
<!-- index.gohtml --> 
{{- template "base.gohtml" . -}} <!--  --> 
{{define "head"}}
  <style>h2 {background-color: yellow;}
  </style>
{{end}}
{{define "body"}}
<h2>Welcome to XXX</h2>
{{end}}
```

where `base.gohtml`

```
{{template "head.gohtml" . -}}
{{template "navbar.gohtml"}}
{{- block "body" . -}}
{{- end -}}
{{template "footer.gohtml"}}
```

[The final version](https://github.com/CarsonSlovoka/go-example-parseFile/blob/e33bca58b16896f401215cb6be325e2a6cfee3b1/src/main.go)