# gin gonic nested templates

Tags: go, templates, go-gin

Go base lib's template has method `Execute` which allows to reference another template in order to use template nesting, like follows:

```
template.Template.Execute("base", data)
```

Also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467731/is-it-possible-to-have-nested-templates-in-go-using-the-standard-library).

**How can I achieve the same but inside gin tonic's http response handler?** Typically it looks like this

```
func about(c *gin.Context) {
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "about.tmpl", gin.H{})
}
```

Which leaves no way to reference another template like with execute.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. From the [Gin documentation](https://gin-gonic.com/docs/examples/multiple-template/):

> Gin allow by default use only one html.Template. Check a [multitemplate render](https://github.com/gin-contrib/multitemplate) for using features like go 1.6 `block template`.

Using [gin-contrib/multitemplate](https://github.com/gin-contrib/multitemplate), as recommended in Gin's docs, we can achieve results similar to the [linked SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11467731/is-it-possible-to-have-nested-templates-in-go-using-the-standard-library):

`templates/base.html`:

```html
<html>
  <head>{{ template "head.html" .context }}</head>
  <body>{{ template "body.html" .context }}</body>
</html>
```

`templates/head.html`:

```html
<title>{{ .title }}</title>
```

`templates/body.html`:

```html
{{ .title }}
```

`main.go`

```golang
package main

import (
    "github.com/gin-contrib/multitemplate"
    "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"
)

// setupRenderer creates a new multitemplate Renderer with templates added.
func setupRenderer() multitemplate.Renderer {
    renderer := multitemplate.NewRenderer()

    renderer.AddFromFiles(
        "myTemplates",
        "templates/base.html",
        "templates/head.html",
        "templates/body.html",
    )

    return renderer
}

// setupRouter initializes a gin Engine, assigns a template renderer, and creates multiple views to return the templates.
func setupRouter() *gin.Engine {
    router := gin.Default()

    router.HTMLRender = setupRenderer()

    router.GET("/", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        ctx.HTML(200, "myTemplates", gin.H{"context": gin.H{"title": "index"}})
    })
    router.GET("/other", func(ctx *gin.Context) {
        ctx.HTML(200, "myTemplates", gin.H{"context": gin.H{"title": "other"}})
    })

    return router
}

func main() {
    router := setupRouter()
    router.Run(":8080")
}
```